# undesired output from polymer 1.0 animation

Tags: polymer

I am very new web developer using polymer 1.0 . I found that when i clicking 
on button repeatedly.It showing undesired output.
likes..example 
http://morethanreal.github.io/neon-animation-demo/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/doc/types.html

thanks in advance.
how i can solve it. basically i m using like above component, and it's showing  undesired output when i clicking repeatedly.

Comment: i think that is the bug talked about in the latest polycast. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwvi1u4XXzc&list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN jump to 15:50

Comment: thanks @jimi for help. But It's not working for me...I solved it by, once user click on button i disabled for listening event till popup window is not disappear. once disappear popup window i made button to listening event again...like concept.